# Property of a trace and norm of the Galois extension

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

Let $L/K$ be a finite extension and let $Tr_{L/K}$ $N_{L/K}$ be its trace and norm of the extension $L/K$ Let $\pi_{\alpha ,K}(X) $ be the minimal polynomial  of  $\alpha$ over $K$ which is split completely as $(X-\alpha_{1})...(X-\alpha_{d})$ over a large enough field extension .then

1)$Tr_{L/K}(\alpha)=[L:K(\alpha)](\alpha_{1}+...+\alpha_{d})$

2)$N_{L/K}(\alpha)=(\alpha_{1}....\alpha_{d})^{[L:K(\alpha)]}$

If we write the minimal polynomial as $\pi _{\alpha}(X)=x^{d}+c_{d-1}X^{d-1}+...+c_{0}.$ then

3)$Tr_{L/K}(\alpha)=-[L:K(\alpha)]c_{d-1}$

4)$N_{L/K}(\alpha)=(-1)^{n}c_{0}^{[L:K(\alpha)]}$

Now let  assume that the extension $L/K$ is Galois with a Galois group

$G=Gal(L/K)$ here we define  the trace and the norm as

$Tr_{L/K}(\alpha)=\displaystyle
\sum_{\sigma \in G } \sigma(\alpha) $,  $ N_{L/K}(\alpha)=\displaystyle\prod_{\sigma \in G }\sigma(\alpha)$

I ask whether the property above of a trace and norm are still correct in the case of Galois extension?

Comment: I think all of the $[K(\alpha):K]$'s should all be replaced by $[L:K(\alpha)]$.

Comment: See the second set of displayed equations in Corollary 5.15 of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/tracenorm.pdf and Theorem 1.1 of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/tracenorm2.pdf.

Comment: @KCd yes i read them but i don't know if that property hold also for the case of Galois extension

Comment: @Abdo if it is true for a general finite extension it is certainly true for one which is Galois.

Comment: @Token Toucan what about property 3 and 4

Comment: @Abdo 3 and 4 are just alternative ways of writing 1 and 2; if you expand the product $(x-\alpha_i)$ and compare the coefficients you'll get exactly those values.

Comment: @Abdo  I don't understand what you mean about not being sure: the concept of norm and trace for a *general* finite extension of fields is defined (as certain coefficients in a characteristic polynomial) in the first file, where your formulas (1) and (2) are worked out. Then at the start of the second file that general notion of trace and norm is shown to equal the sum and product over the Galois group when the field extension is Galois.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension $L|K$ is Galois if it is normal and separable. But since $\pi_{\alpha,K}$ has at least one root in $L$, ($\alpha$ itself) then it contain all roots of $\pi_{\alpha,K}$. Then the extension is the large enough from your claim, hence 1) and 2) holds.

Now, since your $\pi_{\alpha,K}(x)= x^d+c_{d-1}x^{d-1}+...+c_0=(x-\alpha_1)...(x-\alpha_d)$ The identities 3 and 4 follow from the Viete’s formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial), as you wanted.